# Extend the auth.User admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to extend the `auth.User admin`. I want to display inline form. I've added following code. But this code does not work. I am not getting any error. When I click on any particular user's that page keep loading. Am I missing something? Thanks

## model

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=True)
```

## Admin.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
class ReservationInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Reservation
    fk_name = 'publisher'

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    inlines = (ReservationInline,)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

## Edit - 2 runserver output

75 queries strange.

```
DEBUG 2013-08-14 17:03:53,744 middleware 400 4424093696 4 queries run, total 0.041 seconds
[14/Aug/2013 17:03:53] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2506
DEBUG 2013-08-14 17:03:57,405 middleware 400 4424093696 5 queries run, total 0.0 seconds
[14/Aug/2013 17:03:57] "GET /admin/auth/user/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1621
DEBUG 2013-08-14 17:03:57,568 middleware 400 4424093696 2 queries run, total 0.0 seconds
[14/Aug/2013 17:03:57] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 718
DEBUG 2013-08-14 17:07:38,668 middleware 400 4424093696 75 queries run, total 21.408 seconds
[14/Aug/2013 17:07:59] "GET /admin/auth/user/2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10095678
DEBUG 2013-08-14 17:08:18,511 middleware 400 4424093696 2 queries run, total 1.143 seconds
```

## Edit

I've tried other models. They are working fine. But If i use `Reservation` model. It does not work. :(

Comment: Any exceptions shown in the output of `manage.py runserver` ?

Comment: This code seems ok to me. I've just tested it in my current project and it works :/ You might have an error somewhere else

Comment: @Adrián Yeah It works. I've tested it in my other project too. I've noticed one thing. When I use `Reservation` model and click on user's it take 5-10 minutes to open the page. But If I use some other model it works very fine.

Comment: I don't know... is this all the code affecting that page? Do you have signal hooks or overriden `__init__` ?

Comment: @Adrián I've pasted runserver output.

Comment: o.O 21 seconds the translation? wow, I have no idea why it's doing 75 queries for the i18n. Well, that's obviously the problem. I suggest you ask in the django-users mail list. good luck

Comment: Oh, and you could also install djang-debug-toolbar to inspect those queries... that might give you a clue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of User records in your database, then using the Reservation model will cause the page to experience a long delay in loading, if you are not taking advantage of the **raw_id_fields** attribute.

Try...

```
class ReservationInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Reservation
    fk_name = 'publisher'
    raw_id_fields = ('publisher',)
```